# Using a nested query to get details of two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, nested

```
    TABLE 1                                 TABLE 2
id   name    mob                    id      course      mark    
1    joe     0000                    1      English     77
2    john    0000                    2      maths       89
```

I need to show the name of the person from table 1 who has the MAX(grade) in table 2 using a nested query.

```
SELECT t1.name
    FROM t1
    WHERE t1.id = t2.id = (

    SELECT id
    FROM t2 
    WHERE mark = 
     (
    SELECT MAX(mark)
    FROM t2
         ) 
);
```

Comment: A nested query is part of the requirement?

Comment: You can use join query.

Comment: Yes I have to use one for this question

Comment: There are way easier ways to do this.

Comment: I don't see any way to join these tables.

Comment: How do you do it with a join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this satisfies the brief ;-):

```
SELECT a.* 
  FROM table_a a 
  JOIN (SELECT * FROM table_b) b 
    ON b.id = a.id 
 ORDER   
    BY mark DESC 
 LIMIT 1;
```